# Ionic: Trouble saving/loading data from local storage

Tags: save, storage, loading, local, ionic-framework

I'm trying to save data which the application gets from a http.get request and load it the next time the user opens the application without the device connected to the internet.

My data loads fine from the Http.get request but isn't saving or loading.

I'm not sure why my code isn't working. Here's my code:

```
.controller('announcementCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.data = [];
  $scope.infiniteLimit = 1;

  $scope.doRefresh = function() {
    $http.get('http://www.example.com')
      .success(function(data) {
        $scope.data = data;
        window.localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(data));

      })
      .error(function() {
        $scope.data = data;
        if(window.localStorage.getItem("data") !== undefined) {
                $scope.data = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("data"));
            }
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `error`, `$scope.data = data;` will probably set `$scope.data` to `undefined` unless you have some global `data` variable we don't know of. I'm guessing your `error` function should be more like

```
.error(function() { // You don't get any data from here, so setting anything based on it will produce undesired results
    var data = window.localStorage.getItem("data")
    if(data && typeof JSON.parse(data) === "object") {
       $scope.data = JSON.parse(data); // Set the data from local storage
    }
});
```